# How to remove special characters when using .splitlines()

Tags: python-3.x, formatting

I have been working on a script that pulls email data from my gmail account.

Sometimes the output was printed on multiple lines, which caused the CSV formatting to malfunction.

In order to solve this issue, I have tried to use the .splitlines() command. This works really well, however the output looks like this now:

```
['ROSE Bikes News <newsletter@news.rosebikes.com>;10 % AUF DEUTER;22 Aug 2019 11:11:30']
```

Ideally I do not want the following characters ['CONTENT'].

I have tried to use the  .strip() function without success.

```
content = (email_from + ';' + subject + ';' + local_message_date).splitlines()
print(content.strip("[']"))
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I want the output to be not to include [' at the begeinning and '] at the end.

Comment: Just convert the list to a string, `''.join(content)`

Comment: Amazing, it has worked! Thank you very much for your help. You are my hero of the day :)